# Question regarding expected expressions, from Exercise 1-12, in "The C Answer Book"

Tags: c, expression

In K&R, Second Edition, on page 21, exercise 1-12 says, "Write a program that prints its input one word per line."

In using the code from "The C Answer Book", there's one line Xcode gives me a warning on, saying, "Empty character constant", and "Expected Expression". This happens with the first `if` statement, which has the OR operators in them.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1    // inside a word
#define OUT 0   // outside a word

//  print input one word per line
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int c, state;
    
    state = OUT;
    
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
            if (state == IN) {
                putchar('\n');  //  finish the word
                state = OUT;
            } else if (state == OUT) {
                state = IN;     // beginning of word
                putchar(c);
            } else              // inside a word
                putchar(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using the wrong type of "single quotes". You need to use `'` (ASCII single quote) rather than \` (grave accent).

Comment: To clarify, you're using backticks (the key below Esc) for your quotes. You should be using an apostrophe (the key left of Enter) instead. They are not the same character. Also, for future reference here, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Thanks, Ken White, for telling me not to upload pics of code. Duly noted.

To Ken, and the others,

When I use single quotes, the line of the first `if` statement gives a warning, saying, "Empty character constant", as well as, "Expression Expected".

What now?

Comment: you're missing the space between the quotes -- it should be `' '`, not `''`.  You've also got a `}` misplaced resulting in incorrect code (there should be two `}` before the first else)

Comment: Thank you, @ChrisDodd! What's interesting is Xcode doesn't mind, apparently, the misplaced curly brace. Also, interestingly, from "The C Answer Book", there's only one curly brace, after the `else` statement. Not sure why that is, but I guess I'll find out, eventually. Perhaps, it'll take making my way through the C book!

Comment: With the brace misplaced, the code will compile, but won't work (won't do what is described), instead just printing blank lines.  The `else` should associate with the first `if`, not with the second as happens with the misplaced brace.  Misplaced punctuation and similar errors in printed books is all too common.

Comment: Thank you, @ChrisDodd, for all your help! Another question I have, would be, where/how do test a program like this? When I push the play button, in Xcode, the program builds successfully, but it doesn't output anything. Again, where/how would you test a program like this?

Comment: You have to give it some input, either redirecting from a file, or typing into a terminal window somewhere.  I'm not sure exactly how xcode handles either of those.  If xcode pops up a window, try typing in "this is a test" followed by the return key

Answer (score 1):

You used U+0060 GRAVE ACCENT (`` ` ``) where you should have used U+0027 APOSTROPHE (`'`)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong quotes. It has to be **'**  not **`**

On US/UK keyboard:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Ken White, for telling me not to upload pics of code. Duly noted.

To Ken, and the others,

When I use single quotes, the line of the first `if` statement gives a warning, saying, "Empty character constant", as well as, "Expression Expected".

What now?

Comment: @PeterG.Morales because nothing line empty character exists (it is simpy an integer). Empty string (`""`) yes, but not empty character. `getchar` always retunns a value. Simply remove this check

Comment: @gulpur Are you telling me to remove the first expression, in the first `if` statement? The `c == '' `?

Comment: @PeterG.Morales yes